# downloadable fonts - can't download some google fonts

Tags: android, fonts, google-font-api, google-fonts

I am playing with [Downloadable fonts api](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html). I downloaded the  [Google sample application](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DownloadableFonts) and also incorporated the code into my project. Both run successfully but some fonts consistently fail to download both from my app and from the sample app.

I use `FontsContractCompat.requestFont` and gets a callback to `onTypefaceRequestFailed(int reason)` with reason 1. The documentation says it means "FAIL_REASON_FONT_NOT_FOUND". 
I assume those fonts should exist because: 1) They appear in an xml file that comes with the sample app, 2) They appear in the [online list of Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/), and 3) They return from the developer web api (`https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=`)

Here is the list of failed fonts:
 `Angkor
 Archivo
 Asap Condensed
 Baloo Bhaijaan
 Baloo Tammudu
 Battambang
 Bayon
 Bellefair
 BioRhyme Expanded
 Bokor
 Cabin Condensed
 Chau Philomene One
 Chenla
 Content
 Dangrek
 Encode Sans
 Encode Sans Condensed
 Encode Sans Expanded
 Encode Sans Semi Condensed
 Encode Sans Semi Expanded
 Fasthand
 Faustina
 Freehand
 Hanuman
 Khmer
 Koulen
 Libre Barcode 128
 Libre Barcode 128 Text
 Libre Barcode 39
 Libre Barcode 39 Extended
 Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text
 Libre Barcode 39 Text
 Mada
 Manuale
 Metal
 Moul
 Moulpali
 Mukta
 Mukta Mahee
 Mukta Malar
 Nokora
 Open Sans Condensed
 Preahvihear
 Roboto Condensed
 Saira
 Saira Condensed
 Saira Extra Condensed
 Saira Semi Condensed
 Sedgwick Ave
 Sedgwick Ave Display
 Siemreap
 Suwannaphum
 Taprom
 Ubuntu Condensed
 Zilla Slab
 Zilla Slab Highlight`

Comment: I was able to download the font via this link: https://fonts.google.com/download?family=Angkor but I am not sure why it is not working with the api

Comment: Thanks. I also tried that..

Comment: Having the same issue. Really confused as to why some fonts can't be loaded, when the docs say "Which fonts can I use? The entire Google Fonts Open Source collection! Visit https://fonts.google.com to browse."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's definitely weird.  I observed that many (but not all) of those fonts don't have a "latin" or "latin-ext" subset, so that seemed a way to auto-filter them.  I threw together a little python2 script that asks the API for the whole font list, then filters them for "latin" and outputs whats left as a new font-families resource file, which you can redirect to `family_names.xml`.

Usage:     `fontlist.py <API_KEY>`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# fontlist.py by fat-tire
#
# Collects Google provider latin & latin-ext font families and creates a replacement for
# https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DownloadableFonts/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/family_names.xml
#
# See https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api for more info on the Google Fonts API
#
# Usage:     fontlist.py <API_KEY> > family_names.xml

import sys, urllib2, json

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "Usage:"
    print "  fontlist.py <API_KEY> > family_names.xml"
    print "No Google Fonts API key?  Get one at https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api#APIKey"
    sys.exit(0)

APIKEY=sys.argv[1]
url="https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key="

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
try:
    request = urllib2.Request(url + APIKEY)
    conn = opener.open(request)
except Exception, e:
    print "Whoopsie.  Got a " + str(e.code) + " " + str(e.reason) + " error.  You sure that API is legit?"
    sys.exit(1)
data = json.loads(conn.read())

count = 0
items = data["items"]

print "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
print "<!-- Collected from " + url+APIKEY + " -->"
print """<resources>
    <string-array name="family_names">"""
for key in items:
    if "latin" in key["subsets"]:
        print " "*10 + "<item>" + key["family"] + "</item>"
        count = count + 1
print """    <!--Total:  """ + str(count) + """-->
    </array>
</resources>"""
sys.exit(0)
```

This script outputs a [family_names.xml](https://gist.github.com/fat-tire/fb5a4e3617c4738e73af9318ed6720d5) which is interesting.  If you compare it to the [one provided by google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DownloadableFonts/blob/master/app/src/main/res/values/family_names.xml), it does black-out most of the fonts listed in the question. But it doesn't get all of them, including the "Zilla", "Ubuntu", "Barcode" and "Encode" fonts.  Maybe there's something these fonts also have in common that can be used to filter the list further?

Interestingly, the generated list also includes new fonts NOT in the github list, including:

- VolKorn SC
- Spectral
- Spectral SC
- Sedgewick Ave
- Sedgewick Ave Display

...."Barlow", "Bellefair", and a bunch more.  And some of these fonts do seem to work with Android.

So I'm guessing that the list in that demo file is just old.  Maybe there were licensing issues or technical issues that made it necessary to switch up the list.

Regardless it might be worth submitting a pull request with a newer and more up-to-date list that removes the no-longer provided fonts and adds in the ones that the API does offer that are tested and known to work with the provider.

Comment: I am no longer working on the project but you're answer seem helpful enough to merit the credit. I'm sure others will enjoy it if they run into the same issue (and I am, frankly, surprised, that almost no-one seemed to already)