# Download Custom Font to be used in Android Application

Tags: android, android-fonts

I intend to avoid bundling the fonts to my Android application. Hence, i want to know whether fonts can be downloaded on the fly and can be used by my Android Application.

I am already aware of recently introduced [Downloadable Font concept](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html) in Android but that applies only to google fonts.

I want to use this fonts throughout my application (wherever any text is shown in the application).

Please Note:

1. Its not a list of font app user gets to choose from.
2. I am ok launching the application in default font of device, then downloading the custom font from server and using it in the application

Comment: Exactly what is your question? cane you explain in brief? do you wants to set a custom fonts into your control like set in Textview?

Comment: is it something like, store fonts in server, show font list to user, when user click on it, download and use it?

Comment: Its not a list of font a customer gets to choose from. I am ok launching the application in default font of device, then downloading the custom font from server and using it in the application

Comment: Just launch your app in default font and after the starting activity kicks in, add a progress dialog or progress bar and in the background you can download your font and then programmiticaly add it to your views. Use an 'if' condition with the views to check if the font is downloaded or not.

Comment: @AryanRaj I can download the fonts on the fly but dont know how to use them programatically. The only references that i get is to use the fonts bundled into the application

Comment: In that case you can use shared preference to download the file over internet and save it locally on your apps folder in the users storage. And then read the file from there and set it using setTypeFace.

Comment: to set a font on a TextView you can use  textViewName.setTypeface(typeface); "typeface" is received in a callback of "FontsContractCompat.FontRequestCallback()" implemented for "Downloadable Fonts"

Answer (score 2):

From your question it appears you want to have a font available to your app which is downloaded programmatically when the app is run (rather than being bundled with the app).

You also said you are aware of the new [Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts.html) feature, but that "that applies only to google fonts".  This is not correct.  The [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DownloadableFonts/tree/master/app) does use Google Play Services' built-in font provider.  However, according to the documentation, you can also use your *own* font provider backed by your *own* online font-providing server.

I haven't tried this, but I imagine your custom "`FontsProvider`" class (an extended [`ContentProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)) would honor the [`FontsContract`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/FontsContract.html) introduced in API 26.  When it received a [`FontRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/FontRequest.html), it would find the font from its local cache (or alternatively on a server you're running), then return a [`Typeface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) through a [`FontsContract.FontRequestCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/FontsContract.FontRequestCallback.html) exactly as the Google Play Services one does.  (Again, look at the docs-- you have the option to require or not require a certificate.)

A custom `FontProvider` could be bundled within a third-party app (say a typeface company that provides fonts).  But I don't see why you couldn't add your own `FontProvider` within your own app, and have it contact your server and handle all the caching stuff yourself.

Incidentally, if you're curious about the API the Google Font service uses to offer information about the fonts (including links to the actual files), see [here](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api).  In answering another font-related question, I wrote a [very simple python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051069/downloadable-fonts-cant-download-some-google-fonts/48248557#48248557) that gets a list of all the fonts, then parses and filters it, which may be slightly helpful if you decide to write your own back end font provider service.

Comment: Currently I see only Google Fonts Provider bundled with Google Play Services as the only font provider in case of Android and Downloadable Font feature.